# How to send volume +/- on Mac/OSX from Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo, keyboard, mac-os

I saw [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/send-keyboard-media-keys-with-keyboard-library) but I can't find the analog for Mac.

I've tried cycling thru keycodes from 0x01 thru maybe 0x500, and I went thru ascii a few times, also found brightness up/down, and `F11`, `F12`, but they get pressed **with fn key by default** which makes them do operations other than vol +/-.

Comment: What makes you think that the upvoted answer in the other question doesn't apply to Macs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 1) I tried those codes 2) I can't find `xev` for mac.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just untick the "Use all F1, F2, …" in System Preferences -> Keyboard?

[image]

Just wondering if that would be an option and if doing so would create the desired outcome.

Comment: I will try this out!

Comment: it was already unticked, changing it made no difference :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Fn` is hardware and it is handled internally by the keyboard to do something hardware-based without sending any code. So the short answer is: you can't simulate Fn key with arduino.

What I think of as a solution is:

- Create a program on your Mac that can listen for keyboard scan codes to do vol +/- or any other function.
- Send a custom scan code from Arduino to your Mac ( a scan code that isn't part of the standard scan codes ).
- When your listening program receives that code, it should do Vol +/- (or anything else )...

Comment: in my case there is no listening program, the leonardo equiv. board (irduino) is acting **as a keyboard**.

Comment: Oh sorry I may have misunderstood--- you mean to say create a custom mapping on the mac with keys I *can* send, have those alter volume, and run it along-side using the leonardo? This might work; I'm *hoping* to find a way to just send the keycode. I have a 3rd party USB keyboard that sends vol +/- just fine so I know keyboards can do this somehow.

Comment: I don't actually own a Mac, so my solutions are somehow limited, however, check out this page: http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2011/Aug/msg00020.html

Comment: It does say  : " Usage 233 (`0xe9`)  [volume up], Usage 234 (`0xea`)         [volume down]"

Comment: You might want to try these codes and see if that does something ...

Comment: Those third-party keyboards are using some sort of composite HID ( not only HID keyboard but also HID Consumer Device ).

Comment: thank you! it did not end up working, `0xe9` sends a "9" and `0xea` sends "0"

Comment: Yes, as I thought, when your arduino acts like a HID Consumer Device, and you send `0xe9` or `0xea` that will trigger vol+/- ..

Comment: but as long as it is  just a HID keyboard that won't work.